# cakephp jshelper chained select

Tags: jquery, ajax, cakephp

I've been working on this problem for a few days now with no luck.  I'm trying to implement a simple ajax call in CakePHP 2.0 that will populate a select list based on the selection of another select list.  In my database I have vehicle makes and vehicle models.  The models have a make_id field.  When a user selects a make, I want the model select list populated with only models that have a make_id of the one previously selected.  When I view the request in Firebug, it's sending back all models regardless of make_id.  I found this small tutorial that attempts to explain how to populate a select based off another select, but I'm still having no luck.  http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/Calderoy/2011/01/18/how_to_create_an_observefield_equivalent_in_the_new_jshelper

Here is my JsHelper code, found in my view file:

```
$this->Js->get('#CarMakeId')->event(
'change',
$this->Js->request(
    array('controller' => 'CarModels', 'action' => 'get_model'),
        array(
            'async' => true, 
            'update' => '#CarCarModelId',
            'dataExpression' => true, 
            'method' => 'post', 
            'data' => $this->Js->serializeForm(array('isForm' => true, 'inline' => true))
        )
    )
);
```

And here is my controller method:

```
public function get_model() {   
        $models = $this->CarModel->find(
            'all', 
                array('conditions', 
                    array('CarModel.make_id' => $this->data['Car']['make_id'])
                )
            );
        $this->set('car_models', $models);
}
```

Finally, here is my get_model view file:

```
if($car_models) {
echo "<option value=''>-- Select --</option>\n";
foreach($car_models as $model) {
echo "<option value=".$model['CarModel']['id'].">".$model['CarModel']['name']."</option>\n";
}
```

}

This is the javascript that is created via JsHelper:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function () {$("#CarMakeId").bind("change", function (event)     {$.ajax({async:true, data:$("#CarMakeId").serialize(), dataType:"html", success:function (data, textStatus) {$("#CarCarModelId").html(data);}, type:"post", url:"\/Dropbox\/CartrackerV3\/CarModels\/get_model"});
return false;});});
```

//]]>

I have included the RequestHandler helper in my controller.  It's also worth noting that I am getting a response from the ajax call.  After I choose a make, the first option in models changes from a blank option to the -- Select -- option, which comes from the get_model view file, however it is still listing every model in the database, not just the ones with the correct make_id.

Comment: Oops, found the problem! The issue was syntax in my get_model method on the controller. I changed my find call from

$models = $this->CarModel->find(
        'all', 
            array('conditions', 
                array('CarModel.make_id' => $this->data['Car']['make_id'])
            )
        );
To

$models = $this->CarModel->find('all',array(
            'conditions' => array('CarModel.make_id' => $this->data['Car']['make_id'])
                )
            );
Notice the difference in the conditions. I had a comma instead of =>. All is working now.

Comment: Could you please help me to pass multiple values in data parameter of $this->Js->request. I want to post two select box values to the ajax request to populate the third select box.Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the comment by the OP, the issue was just a syntax issue - the comma in:

```
array('conditions', array('CarModel.make_id
```

should be a `=>`:

```
array('conditions' => array('CarModel.make_id
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried to answer my own question but I'm not privied enough to do that yet. :)